# Prove that the sequence $\{a_n|a_n \geq 6 \}$ has finitely many elements

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $5$ then prove that the sequence $\{a_n|a_n \geq 6 \}$ has finitely many elements.

I don't understand how to prove this using the fact that the sequence converges.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

If $a_n$ converges to $5$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N_\epsilon >0,$ such that $n>N_\epsilon$, then $|a_n-5|< \epsilon$.

Choose your $\epsilon$ wisely.

Comment: .....If $|a_n-5|< \epsilon$ then $-\epsilon +5< a_n <\epsilon +5$ then the set is empty ?

Comment: why do you think the set is empty? you might like to work with a concrete sequence for a start when you are stuck.

Comment: ...sorry i think i missed something not understand..can you expalin bit more

Comment: can you solve the problem for $a_n = 5 + \frac{10}{n}$?

Comment: ...means you asking find $a_n's $ values

Comment: ..okie i understand for finite  values the $a_n$ is getting greater than 6 right? so we choose $\epsilon =\frac{10}{n}$

Comment: Try to pick $\epsilon$ to be some positive number that is at most $1$ and independent of $n$. For this particular example, try to figure out what is the corresponding $N$.

Comment: .....thank you so much...i understand now....have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

More guide: There is an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $|a_{n}-5|<1$, then $a_{n}<5+1=6$ for all such $n$.

Comment: @user284331...so $a_n<6 $ for all n right? sorry i am just learner

Comment: Not for all $n$ of course. It is that for all such $n\geq N$. So it might fail for some $n=1,...,N-1$.

Comment: and the  $a_n \geq 6$ for remaining n=1,...N-1 right?

Comment: $a_{n}\geq n$? No, surely not, why you will have this expression.

Comment: i mean $a_n \geq 6$

Comment: No, we don't know what happens for $n=1,...,N-1$.

Comment: @user284331.....confusing sir please explain more

Comment: We are sure that for all $n\geq N$ that $a_{n}<6$, but we are not sure what about $a_{n}$ for $n=1,...,N-1$, but at least we can claim that, there is no way for those $n$ with $a_{n}\geq 6$ are of $\geq N$, so for those $n$ with $a_{n}\geq 6$ must lie inside $n=1,...,N-1$.

Comment: @user284331.....thank you,,,,sorry i wasted you time more.but thank you for your patience ...Have a nice day